# MongoDB: Exclude object from query result where object field equals false

Tags: mongodb

I've been struggling with wrapping my brain around how to exclude a sub-object from a query, if a field of said sub-object is `false`.

Consider this data-set:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    username: ...,
    password: ...,
    name: ...,
    SoMe: {
        facebook: {
            id: ...,
            name: ...,
            email: ...,
            public: false
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I don't want to expose the password, so that's easy:

```
db.collection.findOne({ "username": "whatever" }, { "password": 0 })
```

But I also only want to expose the object `SoMe.facebook` if `SoMe.facebook.public` is `true` - How do I do that?

Comment: Try `db.collection.findOne({ "username": "whatever" , 'SoMe.facebook.public': true}, { "password": 0, 'SoMe.facebook': 1, username: 0, name: 0, _id: 0 })`?

Comment: @zangw This excludes the entire query, if `SoMe.facebook.public` is `false`

Comment: Error: Line 1: Unexpected token {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this one with [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/), show the `SoMe.facebook` field when `SoMe.facebook.public` is true through `$cond`.

```
> db.collection.aggregate([
         {$match: {username:'whatever'}}, 
         {$project: {username: 1, 
                     name:1, 
                     SoMe: {$cond: [{$eq: ['$SoMe.facebook.public', true]}, 
                                   '$SoMe.facebook',
                                    null]}}}
  ])
```

Comment: Well, no... Now SoMe = null, no matter what SoMe.facebook.public is (true/false)

Comment: My bad! I missed a $ in the condition. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

db.collection.find({"SoMe.facebook.public":true},{"SoMe.facebook":1,_id:0})

use this query
 it should result like,
      SoMe: {
          facebook: {
            id: ...,
            name: ...,
            email: ...,
            public: true
        }

Comment: This would return all the instances where SoMe.facebook.public = true. I want to return the entire (user) object and exclude SoMe.facebook from the result if SoMe.facebook.public = false.